# How to fire a trigger on formula field by updating?

Tags: trigger

Here `Amount_c` is the formula field and `Commission_Total__c` is the parent object field where the sum needs to be updated while changing the amount in child object.but the trigger is not firing..please give me solution

```
trigger totalCommissionAmountTrigger on Commission__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    public Map <ID, List<Commission__c >> mapIdList = NEW   Map <ID, List <Commission__c >> ();
    public List <Commission__c > commissionList = NEW List<Commission__c >();
    public List <AVTRRT__Placement__c> placementList = NEW List <AVTRRT__Placement__c>();
    Set <ID> placementId = NEW Set<ID>();   
    if( (Trigger.isInsert) || (Trigger.isUpdate) )
    {
        System.debug('**************');
        for (Commission__c cms: Trigger.New)
        {
            if (cms.Placement__r.Id != null)
            {
                placementId.add(cms.Placement__r.Id);
                system.debug('-----'+placementId);
            }
        }      
        commissionList = [ SELECT 
                             Spread__c ,Commission__c, Amount__c, Placement__r.Id
                           FROM 
                            Commission__c 
                           WHERE    
                            Placement__r.Id IN:placementId];
        for (Commission__c commission:commissionList)
        {
            if (commission.Amount__c !=null)
            {

                mapIdList.put(commission.Placement__r.Id,commissionList);


            }
         }

        placementList = [SELECT Commission_Total__c FROM AVTRRT__Placement__c WHERE Id IN:placementId];
        List <AVTRRT__Placement__c> updatePlacementList = NEW List <AVTRRT__Placement__c>();
        Decimal total = 0;
        for(AVTRRT__Placement__c p:placementList)
        {


               for(Commission__c c:mapIdList.get(p.Id))
               {                     
                     System.debug('////////////'+c.Amount__c); 
                     if (c.Amount__c!=null) 
                     {

                         total += c.Amount__c;
                     }

               }
               p.Commission_Total__c  = total;                  
               system.debug('--------'+p.Commission_Total__c);
               updatePlacementList.add(p);
         }
        update updatePlacementList;

     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger is not firing"? 
Is it that the above trigger doesn't get invoked when a Commission__c record is inserted or updated? Or is it that the trigger is executed but doesn't function as you expect?

Comment: Triggers only execute if the underlying Sobject is affected by a DML event; changes to formula fields are not DML events

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit briefly.You want your trigger to execute only whenever formula field is updated. @sivanee

Comment: yeah...the trigger should fire whenever the formula field gets updated.@Pavan tej

Answer (score 1):

You can have a rollup field and a workflow to update another amount field when rolled up amount is being changed. In this case you can have a trigger to kick in to do what you want it to do on a parent record.